# leaflet custom control in front of everything

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with leaflet and wanted to add some custom controls on my leaflet map. That worked fine. However my problem is, that those custom controls are more in front of the map and not 'on' the map.

So here an example to better understand what i mean: (the navbar is in the same html file as the leaflet map)

I have a navbar and beneath there is the leaflet map. In the left corner of the leaflet map is a custom control (compass). So now when I use the dropdown menu from the navbar, i barely can click on on of the options, as the custom control is 'in front of it' and is blocking the hit bock. (picture below).

Is there a way to put the custom control more on the map than in front of the map?

Here is my custom control (compass):

```
onAdd: function() {
        var controlDiv = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-compass');
        L.DomEvent
          .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation)
          .addListener(controlDiv, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault);
        var compassDiv = document.createElement('div');
        compassDiv.id = 'compassGroup';

        var compassImage = document.createElement('img');
        compassImage.id = 'cpImage';
        compassImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/kompass.png');

        var speedHeadline = document.createElement('h2');
        speedHeadline.id = 'speedHL';

        var arrowImage = document.createElement('img');
        arrowImage.id = 'arImage';

        arrowImage.setAttribute('src', 'images/arrow.png');
        controlDiv.appendChild(compassDiv);
        compassDiv.appendChild(compassImage);
        compassDiv.appendChild(arrowImage);
        controlDiv.appendChild(speedHeadline);
        return controlDiv;
      }
    });

L.control.compass = function(options) {
      return new L.Control.Compass(options);
    };

function initCompass(map, timestamp) {
      var compassControl = L.control.compass();
      map.addControl(compassControl);
      rotateCompass(timestamp);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: use `z-index` to position your elements, give your dropdown and menus higher number z-indexes and the compass a z-index barely higher than the map. Like this, the compass would be behind the dropdowns when required: see more here  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp